# mouseUp event not firing on window object but pointerUp does

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I tried to add mouseUp#EventListener to the **window** object once the child got clicked.

The eventHandler got called, for the below cases.

- Release mouse left-key above child view.
- Though release mouse click above parent view not working, but if I click and mouse up again. Then the eventHandler got fired.

However, the eventHandler not fired for the following cases.

- Release mouse left-key above parent view.

If I changed the event to *pointerUp*, then it's working on all cases.

any idea or tips to debug this on Chrome? The eventListener breakpoint doesn't help much. Because the mouseEvent got ignored. I have no way to stay at the breakpoint.

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: did you use `setPointerCapture`

Answer (score 0):

So

1. if you mouseUp event listener on Child it will work only on child
2. if you mouseUp event listener on Parent it will work on parent and child.

If you added event on Parent and it works for parent and child that is called event delegation

As for breakpoint
Open console -> source -> [on the right side] Event Listener Breakpoints -> Mouse.
Check All Mouse events.

Or you use `debugger` in side of your javascript function.

Comment: only pointer event captures when mouse releases on parent view. none of mouse event got fired. any idea?